# Vlookup with multiple matches

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have an Excel sheet that looks like this..

```
HA-MASTER   CategoryID
38231-S04-A00   14
39790-S10-A03   14
38231-S04-A00   15
39790-S10-A03   15
38231-S04-A00   16
39790-S10-A03   16
38231-S04-A00   17
39790-S10-A03   17
38231-S04-A00   18
39790-S10-A03   18
38231-S04-A00   19
39790-S10-A03   19
38231-S04-A00   20
39790-S10-A03   20
38231-S04-A00   21
39790-S10-A03   21
38231-S04-A00   22
39790-S10-A03   22
38231-S04-A00   23
```

Is there any way to do a vlookup (or something similar) to return something like:

```
14    38231-S04-A00, 39790-S10-A03
15    38231-S04-A00, 39790-S10-A03

etc...
```

Comment: Are the rows always paired by Category ID (will all category IDs always have 2 rows?). If so you can do it doing 2 `VLOOKUPS` and then concatenate the results.

Comment: If the number of rows per Category is indeterminate then you can't resolve this elegantly with formulas and you would need at least a UDF that concatenates an array. With that you can use `IF`s and array formulas to pull all rows that match and then join them using the UDF. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a crude way to do it via formula and a 3rd column.

1) In your 3rd column use the follow formula and extend it down.
    =IF(B2=B3,A2&", "&C3,A2)

Note: This assumes your example starts on cell A1. Where A1 = "HA-MASTER"

2) Now have your VLOOKUP run and it return the 3rd column on match (instead of the 1st column). VLOOKUP returns the first result it matches, which is now a concatenation of all rows that match it's ID number.

Note: You'll need to make sure all rows are sorted based on Column B (CategoryID) for this to work.

Note2: I am assuming you are looking for the concatenated list, without the CategoryID concatenated to your result.

Comment: Thank you, this would work if I only had 2 numbers per each category. I should have used a larger data sample in my question... is there a way I can change this so that ALL of the "HA-MASTER" numbers are included even if there are more rows than 2?

Comment: I updated the formula, it should work as intended now (with as many rows as you need). Since I did it freehand without double checking my work, I made a mistake. I changed 'A3' to 'C3', so it accumulates now.